# How to use qml files specified in a different qrc resource file?

Tags: qt, qml

In all the examples I've seen, all qml files in the project are packed inside a single "qml.qrc", sometimes under different prefixes or in different directories.

To access items from a different qml file, one just has to import them.

- If the files are under the same prefix, but in a different physical directory, then it's `import "dirname"`
- If the files are under a different prefix, it's `import "qrc:/prefixname/dirname"`

However, what to do if the item in question is in a different qrc file?

The [documentation](http://doc.qt.io/qt-5/resources.html) doesn't mention this. Is there a good place where everything regarding `import` is presented in detail? How to import a single file, how to import whole directories, what if the files are in different folders, different prefixes, different resources, etc. I couldn't find one.

If I use loaders, I can specify the target as `source:"qrc:///qrcname/filename"`. Is this the only way?

What I would like to do is to separate styles into a different resource file, to not clutter my main "qml.qrc".

So I would have

```
Button
{
    style: MyButtonStyle{}
    //...
}
```

in my main qml, and `MyButtonStyle.qml` in a different qrc file. Is that possible, or must the style be specified in the same qrc file?

Answer (score 1):

It does not matter how many separate `.qrc` files you have. Resources listed in all of them are visible the same way. If you have conflicting file names, use prefixes to disambiguate.

Comment: This answer is of no use without also telling how to import it. I tried all 3 ways presented in the question, and none of them worked. Before I blindly continued trying all imaginable possibilities, I looked in the documentation, didn't find anything, this is why the question was posted.

Comment: If your .qml file is in the resources, you can import other resource folders using relative paths (`import "dirname"`). Alternatively, you can always pass the full path as you've noted in your original post.

Comment: Use `QDirIterator it(":/", QDirIterator::Subdirectories); while (it.hasNext()) qDebug() it.next();` in `main()` to print out all the resources in your app. Perhaps the structure is not what you think it is.

Answer (score 0):

It seems that will be mounted as default `qrc` file.
You can use `QResource::registerResource()` to register it with an specific mount point such this:

```
// something...

QResource::registerResource(myQrcPath, "/second_source");

// something...
```

and use as follow for example:

```
loader.setSource("qrc:/second_source/MyBigPage.qml");
```